# Icons error windows 10 phonegap build

Tags: windows, cordova, build, icons

I have a small problem with the icons on windows 10 build app

So when i submit i have this error :

```
Image file StoreLogo.scale-100.png is a default image.
Image file Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png is a default image.
Image file Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png is a default image.
```

In my config.xml i have that :

```
<platform name="windows">

<icon src="res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="50" height="50"  />
<icon src="res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="150" height="150" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="150"  />
<icon src="res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="310"   />

</platform>
```

And my zip is like that :

[myzip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCoE3.png)

One of you have the solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody have a solution ?